# Concatenation of array of strings

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I have the following, I am creating a link dynamically I am stuck with concatenation of a split.

```
link = "<li><span id='number'>" + link.split(" ")[0] + ".</span>" // Adding a "peroid" character after the reason number and make it bold 
        + "<a href='#" + reasonTitle + "' " // Open link tag off adding href with relevant reference
        + "onclick=\"_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'" + experimentConversionReference + "\', \'ReasonClicked\', \'" + reasonTitleSpaces + "\'])\;\">" // Adding event tracking for google
        + link.split(/\d/)[1] // Add back on the back end of the split string
        + "</a>" // Close link tag off
        + "</li>";
```

More specifically `line 4` on the above I want to grab and print everything in the array from `[1]` and up how can I do this?

What I don't want is to do

```
link.split(/\d/)[1] + link.split(/\d/)[2]  + link.split(/\d/)[3]  + link.split(/\d/)[]
```

and so on.

Comment: You should consider adopting a template framework, e.g. https://github.com/janl/mustache.js.

Comment: adding some input en expected output would help understanding the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to split, just get the part of the string after the space:

```
link.substr(link.indexOf(" ") + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
link.split(/\d/).slice(1).join('')
```

Comment: This is great however I loose the number on from the second split. `1 My Example 200 String.` would return "My Example String" when I want "My Example 200 string"

Comment: @Anicho I thought, that you had problems only with spliting and concating, so I have provided the solution for resolving only that :).

Answer (score 1):

Split and join, excluding first item:

```
var joined  = link.split(/\d/);
joined .shift(); // remove first item
joined .join(''); // join the array
```

And then use it like:

```
link = "<li><span id='number'>" + link.split(" ")[0] + ".</span>" // Adding a "peroid" character after the reason number and make it bold 
        + "<a href='#" + reasonTitle + "' " // Open link tag off adding href with relevant reference
        + "onclick=\"_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'" + experimentConversionReference + "\', \'ReasonClicked\', \'" + reasonTitleSpaces + "\'])\;\">" // Adding event tracking for google
        + joined // Add back on the back end of the split string
        + "</a>" // Close link tag off
        + "</li>";
```

Comment: nice thanks for the working example went with the .substr example